# DevExpress ASPxComboBox Items Color Change from Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, treelist

I have a `ASPxComboBox` for which I'm binding data based on 2 conditions.
Now,I need to show `Color` for items in `combobox` based on condition.

My Code :

```
var dataMainBranchUsers = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_USER_DETAILS
                                               where xx.BRANCH_ID == 1 && (xx.USER_LEVEL == 2 || xx.USER_LEVEL == 5)
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                   xx.USER_NAME,
                                                   xx.USER_ID,
                                                   xx.USER_LEVEL
                                               }).ToList();

                    DataTable dtMainBranchUsers = LINQToDataTable(dataMainBranchUsers);

                    for (int i = 0; i < dtMainBranchUsers.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string strlevel = dtMainBranchUsers.Rows[i]["USER_LEVEL"].ToString();
                        string struser = dtMainBranchUsers.Rows[i]["USER_NAME"].ToString();
                        if (strlevel == "2")
                        {
                            dtMainBranchUsers.Rows[i]["USER_NAME"] = struser + " - Admin";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dtMainBranchUsers.Rows[i]["USER_NAME"] = struser + " - Survey User";
                        }
                    }

                    Cmb_UserName.TextField = "USER_NAME";
                    Cmb_UserName.ValueField = "USER_ID";
                    Cmb_UserName.DataSource = dtMainBranchUsers;
                    Cmb_UserName.DataBind();
```

Now, I need to differentiate based on `USER_LEVEL` and show colors.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From DevExpress

> *I'm afraid, the ASPxListBox (which is the part of the ASPxComboBox) doesn't allow to set specific color for each item. 
>   I suggest you to use the ASPxDropDownEdit. This control allows to put anything in its DropDownWindowTemplateContainer. 
>   For example, you can put the ASPxGridView and set color for each row using the HtmlRowPrepared event handler.*

See [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q234557).